# AWStats log format for tomcat access logs which has X-Forwarded-For

Tags: awstats

What should be the AWStats log format for below tomcat access logs ?

I tried these formats but the external IP addresses are not coming into AWStats reports.

```
LogFormat="%host %other %logname %time1 %methodurl %code %bytesd %refererquot %uaquot %referer %other %other"

LogFormat="%other %other %logname %time1 %methodurl %code %bytesd %refererquot %uaquot %host_proxy"
```

tomcat valve settings:

```
pattern="%h %l %{USER_ID}s %t &quot;%r&quot; %s %b &quot;%{Referer}i&quot; &quot;%{User-Agent}i&quot;  &quot;X-Forwarded-For=%{X-Forwarded-For}i&quot;  &quot;JSESSIONID=%{JSESSIONID}c&quot; %D"
```

Log entry:

```
127.0.0.1 - - [04/Nov/2013:13:39:55 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 12345 "https://www.google.com/url?some_url" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/30.0.1599.101 Safari/537.36"  "X-Forwarded-For=real_ip, proxy_server_internal_ip"  "JSESSIONID=-" 12345
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$ echo $STR
127.0.0.1 - - [10/Nov/2013:04:14:03 +0000] "GET /XXXX/js/service.js HTTP/1.1" 200 656 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:24.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/24.0" "X-Forwarded-For=75.67.17.69, 10.2.0.121" "JSESSIONID=YYYY" 2

$ echo $STR | perl -pe 's/X\-Forwarded\-For=([\d\.]+).*?\"/X-Forwarded-For=$1"/g'
127.0.0.1 - - [10/Nov/2013:04:14:03 +0000] "GET /XXXX/js/service.js HTTP/1.1" 200 656 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:24.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/24.0" "X-Forwarded-For=75.67.17.69" "JSESSIONID=YYYY" 2
```

Comment: Welcome to server fault!  While it's great to give examples, it's nice to explain what is being done so it's useful to future readers as well.  Additionally, I've cleaned up the formatting - note that you can mark code segments with a 4-space indent.

Comment: This perl one liner extracts first IP address from X-Forwarded-For field in access log

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the help.

Did one more trick, awstat wants host_proxy logs as 75.67.17.69, 10.2.0.121, so changed your perl command as below which changes "X-Forwarded-For=75.67.17.69, 10.2.0.121" to "75.67.17.69, 10.2.0.121" without quotes and extra spaces removed.

perl -pe 's/ "X-Forwarded-For=([\d.,\s]+).*?" /$1/g'

After the changes the logs are provided to awstat for processing.